# My element condition is not having an impact on the element visibility

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a condition to display the arrow up or arrow down depending on the column's order.  However, neither arrows are appearing no matter what the state.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { IoCaretDown } from "react-icons/io5";
import { IoCaretUp } from "react-icons/io5";

function Countries() {

  const [nameOrder, setNameOrder] = useState('asc');
  const [contOrder, setContOrder] = useState('asc');
  const [popOrder, setPopOrder] = useState('asc');
  console.log('name', nameOrder);
  
  const sortByName = () => {
    const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) => {
      if (nameOrder === 'asc') {
        if (b.name.common > a.name.common) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (b.name.common > a.name.common) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      } else {
        if (b.name.common < a.name.common) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (b.name.common < a.name.common) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }
    });
    setData(sorted);
    console.log('nameOrder', nameOrder)
    let newOrder = nameOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    setNameOrder(newOrder);
    console.log('nameOrder', nameOrder)
  };

  const sortByContinent = () => {
    const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) => {
      if (contOrder === 'asc') {
        if (b.continents > a.continents) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (b.continents > a.continents) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      } else {
        if (b.continents < a.continents) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (b.continents < a.continents) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }

    });
    setData(sorted);
    console.log('current order', contOrder)
    let newOrder = contOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    setContOrder(newOrder);
    console.log('current order', contOrder)
  };

  const sortByPopulation = () => {
    const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) => {
      if (popOrder === 'asc') {
        return a.population - b.population;
      } else {
        return b.population - a.population;
      }
    });
    setData(sorted);
    console.log('popOrder', popOrder)

    let newOrder = popOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    setPopOrder(newOrder);
    console.log('popOrder', popOrder)
  };

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all?fields=name,continents,population,flag')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((apiData) => {
        setData(apiData);
      }, []);
    console.log('data', data)

  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Country Table Data</h1>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={sortByName}>
              Name
              {nameOrder === 'desc' ?? <IoCaretDown />}
              {nameOrder === 'asc' ?? <IoCaretUp />}
            </th>
            <th onClick={sortByContinent}>
              Continent
              <IoCaretDown />
              <IoCaretUp />

            </th>
            <th onClick={sortByPopulation}>
              Population
              <IoCaretDown />
              <IoCaretUp />
            </th>
            <th>Flag</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((country) => (
            <tr key={country.flag}>
              <td>{country.name.common}</td>
              <td>{country.continents}</td>
              <td>{country.population}</td>
              <td>{country.flag}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Countries;
```

In the table header is where I've added the condition:

Name
{nameOrder === 'desc' ?? }
{nameOrder === 'asc' ?? }

Notice the Name column has no arrows even though the console logs clearly show the state is 'asc'

[image]

Comment: `??` is the ["nullish coalescing" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing), essentially `x ?? y` means "`y` if `x` is `null` or `undefined`". Instead of `{nameOrder === 'desc' ?? <IoCaretDown />}` you want `{nameOrder === 'desc' && <IoCaretDown />}` etc

Comment: Additionally, your conditions in each of the sorting methods are the same for each sort direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use double question marks `??` to conditionally render the element. The correct way is either use the ternary operator `?` or logical `AND` operation

Ternary

```
<th onClick={sortByName}>
  Name
  {nameOrder === 'desc' ? <IoCaretDown /> : null}
  {nameOrder === 'asc' ? <IoCaretUp /> : null}
</th>

// or this one line code 

<th onClick={sortByName}>
  Name
  {nameOrder === 'desc' ? <IoCaretDown /> : nameOrder === 'asc' ? <IoCaretUp /> : null}
</th>
```

Logical

```
<th onClick={sortByName}>
  Name
  {nameOrder === 'desc' && <IoCaretDown />}
  {nameOrder === 'asc' && <IoCaretUp />}
</th>
```